# Regularization LSTM for a Time Series forecast

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecast

I have a dataframe with 220 rows and 1410 columns. The rows represents a datetime in days and the columns represents 470 differents features in three time lags (470 * 3 = 1410) as we can see below:

```
            CEE_SECO_01_lag1  CEE_SECO_02_lag1  ...    BM_lag3   PME_lag3
2017-07-31          30553.75          28373.42  ...  266325.00  217874.92
2017-08-01          30656.70          28715.36  ...  266325.00  217874.92
2017-08-02          30600.47          28341.33  ...  266325.00  217874.92
2017-08-03          28468.36          26797.55  ...  266325.00  217874.92
2017-08-04          29081.35          27373.21  ...  266325.00  217874.92
                     ...               ...  ...        ...        ...
2018-03-03          33249.36          31572.65  ...  262770.31  218720.93
2018-03-04          36189.80          34308.52  ...  262770.31  218720.93
2018-03-05          36082.87          33824.52  ...  262770.31  218720.93
2018-03-06          35227.69          32910.53  ...  262770.31  218720.93
2018-03-07          35891.20          33809.99  ...  262770.31  218720.93

[220 rows x 1410 columns]
```

I am trying to run LSTM model for a forecast problem.

First i reshaped my data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n_samples = len(X_train)
n_steps = 3
n_features = int(len(X_train.columns)/n_steps)
                
X_train_lstm = X_train.to_numpy().reshape((n_samples,n_steps,n_features))
X_teste_lstm = X_test.to_numpy().reshape((1,n_steps,n_features))

y_treino_lstm = y_train.to_numpy()
y_teste_lstm = y_test.to_numpy()
```

Then, I create a Vanilla LSTM model (like this https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/):

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense 

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=1000)
```

And works perfectly. But when I am trying to make a regularization in this  model (like this: https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-weight-regularization-lstm-networks-time-series-forecasting/), I am getting stucked.

If I try this:

```
from keras.regularizers import L1L2

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=0.01, l2=0.0) , input_shape=(n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=1000)
```

This error occurs:

```
ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, it needs to know its batch size. Specify the batch size of your input tensors: 
- If using a Sequential model, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_input_shape` argument to your first layer.
- If using the functional API, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_shape` argument to your Input layer.
```

And if I try to change **input_shape** to **batch_input_shape** like this:

```
n_batchs = 1

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=0.01, l2=0.0) , batch_input_shape=(n_batchs, n_steps, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X_train_lstm, y_train_lstm, epochs=1000)
```

I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Specified a list with shape [1,470] from a tensor with shape [32,470]
     [[node sequential_3795/lstm_3791/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor (defined at C:\Users\Pichau\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:4330) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_48158087]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential_3795/lstm_3791/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor:
 sequential_3795/lstm_3791/transpose (defined at C:\Users\Pichau\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py:4199)

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I've already tried lot of different values of n_batchs, like 32, 28, the number of features, observations, columns or time steps and some random values.

How i can make a regularization with LSTM model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put together a example for you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

X, y = make_regression()
print(X.shape, y.shape)
lstm_train = []
for i in range(0,100,10):
    for j in range(0,100,10):
        lstm_train.append(X[j:j+10])

lstm_train = np.stack(lstm_train, axis=0)
print(lstm_train.shape)

from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import L1L2
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(10, 100)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(50, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = L1L2(l1=0.01, l2=0.0)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.fit(lstm_train, y, epochs=10)
```

The crux is in this line. We can add an exclusive `InputLayer` in the model and specify the dimensions there instead of doing it in the LSTM layer.

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(10, 100)))
```